# IntegratorKey for app with multiple users DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question about integratorkey on DocuSign. Can I do an app that uses my integratorkey but that other users can use?

I want that a user specify his user and password and then login with this information in my app with my integratorkey. Can I do this or I need that each user puts his own integratorkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Integrator Key identifies the *integrating application*, not necessarily a specific DocuSign Account.  In other words, even though the Integrator Key was provisioned through and is affiliated with your own DocuSign account, you ***can*** use that key to facilitate API access to other DocuSign accounts (in the same environment of course -- i.e., DEMO or PROD). Simply ensure that the API calls use the Base Url (i.e., including account number) and credentials (username/password) that correspond to the account you want to access.

Comment: Ok, a lot of thanks! Let me to do another question, is the first time that I use DocuSign API. When I finish my app, what can I do to obtain an integratorkey for use in PROD with other PROD credentials?

Comment: DocuSign requires you to go through an API certification process before your Integrator Key will work in the PROD environment. Info about that process can be found here:  http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification